# Unexpected RSpec #should_receive behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

surely I'm missing something... but what!?

in my spec I've

```
User.should_receive(:find).with("1").and_return(@user)
```

and in my controller

```
User.find(params[:id])
```

green light... correct...

but if I change my controller using another method, for example first:

```
User.first
```

or even

```
User.all
```

I get green light too... I was expecting an error like

```
expected: 1 time
received: 0 times
```

could anyone give me a hint to understand that behaviour?

many thanks

EDIT

here you could find more info about this issue: https://gist.github.com/3848429#file_user_controller_spec.rb

EDIT 2

my spec now, but I still need to check with method is calling each #find...

```
describe "GET #show" do
  before(:each) do
    @user = mock_model(User)
    should_authorize(:show, @user)
  end

  it "assigns the requested user to @user" do
    User.should_receive(:find).with("1").twice.and_return(@user)
    get :show, id: "1"
  end
  it "renders the :show template" do
    get :show, id: "1"
    response.should render_template :show
  end
end
```

Comment: The behavior you're seeing is not expected so there must be something else going on. Could you post more of your spec?

Comment: hi, @Beerlington I've edited my question adding more details. browse the Gist to see the full info. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you need both `User.stub!(:find)...` and `User.should_receive(:find)...` since the should_receive basically acts like a stub. I would remove the first one and see if that that changes the behavior.

Comment: if I remove `User.stub!(:find)...` I get this error https://gist.github.com/3858583

Comment: Looks like it's just getting called twice. What does `should_authorize(:show, @user)` do? Any chance that is calling User.find? Any chance your controller is calling it twice?

Comment: It's related to `ability.rb` (CanCan). You could find more on `#should_authorize` and my CanCan settings in the same Gist https://gist.github.com/3848429#file_controller_helper.rb

Comment: ok, using `User.should_receive(:find).with("1").twice` give now green light. So definitely CanCan `#authorize!` call User.find somewhere (I've looked at CanCan code but I couldn't find that call). Now how could I "detect" which method is calling the two `#find`? It would be helpful. Many thanks!!!

Comment: I mean something like (pseudo code)

`User.should_receive(:find).with("1").called_by(User.authorize!)`